# While using Application Modeler Not able to see Identify button after Launch in Firefox

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, blueprism

I am using Blue Prism for gmail login test, I want to try with different Browser,I tried with IE every thing is fine but while trying with Firefox, not able to find Identify button  after Launch. What would be the reason ? Is there any thing like Blue Prism doesn't support Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know and what I've been taught, Blue Prism works ONLY with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Blue Prism is compatible with the Internet Explorer browser only, you are advised to use IE while spying the web element, It does not support other browsers.It has the default setting of Internet Explorer, You can see this when you define the root node(brwoser+ URL path) in appln modular it shows the path with internet explorer.

Hope this helps.